# where to get the name of excel file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, filenames, sharepoint

There are some documents stored in a SharePoint document list. Using a IE browser, we have the option of opening the file directly in Excel. But on doing this, excel starts and downloads the file and then opens it.

I am actually trying to copy the filename to clipboard, but finding it impossible.

[image]

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Copying the filename as text? You can't highlight it and copy it that way? What version sharepoint?

Comment: Um, not from sharepoint...from the opened excel app itself...! The file is downloaded from SP.! We use MS-Office 2013

Comment: You can mount the sharepoint location as a network drive under windows - you will be able to see the files as normally on a harddrive. Details of the procedure: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn151472.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From inside Excel.

Go to File --> Save As and it will open up a new explorer window and you can access the file name there.

The backstage screen you are on has the location URL - so if you click it it takes you to the library where you can access the document file name as well.